# MATLAB store indices maximum in logical matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, matrix-indexing

Lets say I have a 4 dimensional matrix, from which I would like to retrieve the maximum values over the 2nd and 3rd dimension.

```
A = rand(4, 4, 4, 4);
[max_2, in_2] = max(A, [], 2);
[max_3, in_3] = max(max_2, [], 3);
```

How could I use `ind_2` and `ind_3` to obtain a logical 4 dimensional matrix, where a `1` entry means this entry is maximum in the 2nd and 3rd dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach working with linear indices and uses argmax indices from `max` function, so it would only consider the first argmax in case of ties for the max value -

```
% Get size parameters
[m,n,p,q] = size(A);

% Reshape to merge second and third dims
[~, in_23] = max(reshape(A,m,[],q), [], 2);

% Get linear indices equivalent that could be mapped onto output array
idx1 = reshape(in_23,m,q);
idx2 = bsxfun(@plus,(1:m)', m*n*p*(0:q-1)) + (idx1-1)*m;

% Initialize output array an assign 1s at linear indices from idx2
out = false(m,n,p,q);
out(idx2) = 1;
```

**Explanation with a sample**

1) Input array :

```
>> A
A(:,:,1,1) =
     9     8
     9     1
A(:,:,2,1) =
     2     9
     8     1
A(:,:,1,2) =
     1     7
     8     1
A(:,:,2,2) =
     8     5
     9     7
```

2) Reshape array for a better visualization :

```
>> reshape(A,m,[],q)
ans(:,:,1) =
     9     8     2     9
     9     1     8     1
ans(:,:,2) =
     1     7     8     5
     8     1     9     7
```

3) The question is to take max value from each of the rows. For that, we had `idx2` as the linear indices :

```
>> idx2
idx2 =
     1    13
     2    14
```

Looking back at the reshape version, thus we chose (bracketed ones) -

```
>> reshape(A,m,[],q)
ans(:,:,1) =
    [9]     8     2     9
    [9]     1     8     1
ans(:,:,2) =
     1     7     [8]     5
     8     1     [9]     7
```

So, looking closely, we see that for the first row, we had two `9s`, but we are choosing the first one only.

4) Finally, we are assigning these into the output array initialized as logical zeros :

```
>> out
out(:,:,1,1) =
     1     0
     1     0
out(:,:,2,1) =
     0     0
     0     0
out(:,:,1,2) =
     0     0
     0     0
out(:,:,2,2) =
     1     0
     1     0
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use this approach:

```
A = rand(4, 4, 4, 4); % example data
B = permute(A, [1 4 2 3]); % permute dims 2 and 3 to the end
B = reshape(B, size(A,1), size(A,4), []); % collapse last two dims
C = bsxfun(@eq, B, max(B, [], 3)); % maximize over collapsed last dim
C = reshape(C, size(A,1), size(A,4), size(A,2), size(A,3)); % expand dims back
C = permute(C, [1 3 4 2]); % permute dims back. This is the final result
```

Comment: Very nice approach. However, If there are multiple elements in A that have the maximum value in the 2nd or 3rd dimension, I would like only the first (a.k.a. the value of index in_2 and in_3) to be 1. the rest must be 0.

Comment: @user1111652 Thanks. Pity that your question didn't specify that